# JavaScript ternary operator into full if/else statement issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have following ternary statement:

```
$.history.init(function(url) {
        load(url == "" ? "#some-page" : url);
});
```

Which I have rewrote into:

```
$.history.init(function(url) {
         load( 
               if( url == ""){ url = "#some-page"
               } else { url = url }
         );
 });
```

I now the is an error on line 3 `if(url == "")`, but I don't understand what error.
Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, an `if` is *not* an expression. It does not return a value and cannot be put inside a function call. That is, this is not valid:

```
func(if (a) { ... } else { ... });
```

This is the main difference between `if` and `?:`--the operator is an expression and returns a value; `if` is a statement, does *not* return a value and cannot be used everywhere.

Your best bet if you have to avoid the ternary operator is to do something like:

```
if (url == "") {
  url = "#some-page";
} 

load(url);
```

You can also achieve the same effect using `||`:

```
function (url) {
  load(url || "#some-page");
}
```

This is the shortest and most idiomatic way to write your code.

Answer (score 1):

`if` expressions dont return anything in JS.  So that basically does `load(undefined)`.

Try this instead:

```
if (url === '') {
  url = '#some-page';
}

load(url);
```

Note you don't need to `else` at all, because if the value is present you have nothing to change.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite it as

```
$.history.init(function(url) {
        if( url == ""){ 
           url = "#some-page";
         }
         load( url );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewritten code is invalid. Try this:

```
$.history.init(function(url) {
      if(url == "") {
         load("#some-page");
      } else {
         load(url);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `if` statement to be outside of the `load` function, i.e.

```
$.history.init(function(url) {
    if (url === "") { 
        url = "#some-page";
    }
    load(url);
});
```

Note that you don't need the `else` clause as `url = url` is a redundant operation.